# Detect Duplicate and loop in XML

Tags: xml, recursion, duplicates

I am trying to achieve the below 2 things, when loading and parsing XML file recursively.
1. Avoid duplicates
2. Avoid loops.

My XML file contains other XML file names as well. I have to load the main file first, then parse file names under  tag. Once parsing completed, i have to load and parse these files one by one. While i doing these, i have to show message for duplicates or loops recursively. Please suggest me the algorithm/ links to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a list of all of the "things" (XML file names in your case) that you have processed. Then, before you process each item, check to see if it is already in the list and warn/error accordingly.

The best way to track this--a linked list, array, dictionary, hash set, etc.--list will depend on the programming/scripting language you are using and the number of entries you expect the "seen items" list to contain.

Comment: Thanks. I am using VC++ dictionary to track the items.After check, i have to display error for loop and warning for duplicate. But while checking, both are detected as duplicate only. Is there any way to find item for recursive.

Comment: Assuming that you are calling your load function itself recursively, pass the same dictionary into the recursice calls. Then when you load "Main.xml" you add it to the list and call the function to load "Child.xml". "Child.xml" gets added to the list after it is loaded and if it tries to load "Main.xml" again, it sees it is already on the list. Does that make sense?